# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$ What is the impact on the site?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is the effect of the .htaccess code on the site. When I add .htaccess, if the site doesn't have any extensions (.html - .php - .js - .png ...), it adds "/" to the end of the url.

What is the seo effect on this site? My site content is advertised site. What if I don't add this code?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.The Apache module mod_rewrite(RewriteEngine On) allows you to rewrite URL requests that come into your server and is based on a regular-expression parser
2.RewriteEngine On enables mod_rewrite.
3.RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z] - Grabs the entered address.
4.RewriteRule . ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} - Uses the 'lc' variable that was added to the vhost 5.file to convert all characters to lowercase. 
6.[R=301,L] - Performs a 301 redirect and also stops any later rewrite rules from affecting this URL (a good idea to add after the last rule). It's on the same line as RewriteRule, at the end.